# (All variants) How to execute specific command with any command entered?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ksh, zsh

After executing some util (after pressing Enter) I would like shell to echo 'Oklahoma!' or execute anything else. i.e.:

```
root@host$ somecommand --version
Some command version 1.00
Oklahoma!
root@host$ ls -la
.
..
dr-xr-xr-x root root 0 Apr 28 2014 file1
dr-xr-xr-x root root 0 Apr 28 2014 file2
Oklahoma!
root@host$ uname -a
Linux hostname 2.6.24-21-generic #1 SMP Mon Aug 25 16:57:51 UTC 2008 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Oklahoma!
```

Personally I believe that solution is in bashrc, but I don't know how to do this properly. However if you have any other solution, please post it.

Comment: You can maybe create a function as a wrapper. When you call it, it will execute the given command and then echo Oklahoma.

Comment: @fedorqui Then I would have to make functions for all commands/utils.

Comment: Can you not just set $PS1?

Comment: @AdamBurry echo is just an example - it should be replaced with any other command

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x279.html

Comment: @AdamBurry thanks for the tip - it may be a solution. see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably after the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable.

The `man bash` says:

> If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.